# Java SSLSocket InputStream read() blocks after first connection

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I have a simple program that creates muitple SSL Socket connections to a server that send back simple text data. The first ssl connections works fine. After I create the 2nd ssl connection to the same server and port, the execution blocks at the read() call. If I create mutiple separate programs that just do one connection each and run them in parallel, it works fine. SO the server can handle multiple parallel connections. Its just when I create more than one consecutive connections from the same program, read() blocks. I close the first connection before opening the 2nd. One more thing, I could not reproduce the issue when both the server and client running on the same machine, only happens when server is run remotely. Any suggestion/idea what is going on? Any input is much appreciated.

```
public static int getPort(String agentHost, int agentPort, String token) {
int port_num = 0;
 InputStream in = null;
 BufferedWriter out = null;
 SSLSocket s = null;
try {
    s = (SSLSocket) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket(agentHost, agentPort);
    String message = token;

    out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
    out.write(message);
    out.flush();

    in =s.getInputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
    System.out.println("Waiting on read");
    int bytes_read = in.read(buffer);
    System.out.println("read " + bytes_read + " bytes" );
    if(bytes_read > 0) {
        String port_s = new String(buffer, 0, bytes_read, "UTF-8");   // if the charset is UTF-8  
        port_s = port_s.trim();
        port_num = Integer.parseInt(port_s);
    } 
    else 
        System.out.println("------Error in call---------");
    }  
 catch ( IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
 finally {
     try {
         if(s != null) s.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
         }
 }
return port_num;
```

}

Comment: The problem is clearly at the server end, somehow. It isn't sending.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, it was an issue with the server. it was not sending.